# How to access only for admin to login the page?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I want the only staff whose role is **A** (A=Administrator) in the Staff Table can access the administrator module. I want Mary Tan can only access to login while the rest of the staff cannot access.

Here is the output:

[click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ6K2.jpg)

Database:

[click db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhUlu.jpg)

Here's my code:

```
 SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        string connectionString = null;
        string staffName = null;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public bool CheckValidUser(string Username, string Password)
        {
            bool valid = false;
            SqlDataReader dr = null;

            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LeaveManagementCS"].ConnectionString;

            string sql = "SELECT * from Staff WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Pwd";

            try
            {
                conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pwd", Password);

                conn.Open();

                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    staffName = dr["StaffName"].ToString();
                    valid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblOutput.Text = "There is an error logging in. Please check username or password.";
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblOutput.Text = "Error Message: " + ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
            }
            return valid;
        }

        protected void tbLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool validUser = CheckValidUser(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text);

            if (validUser)
            {
                Session["StaffName"] = staffName;

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(staffName, false);

                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(staffName, false);
            }
            else
            {

                lblOutput.Text = "Invalid User. Please try again.";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: So what is your actual problem ?

Answer (score 0):

change sql query like this:

```
string sql = "SELECT * from Staff WHERE Username=@Username AND Password=@Pwd And Role=N'A';
```